# How is the programming pattern called that I used here (to simplify error handling during dictionary accesses)?

Tags: python, design-patterns, error-handling

I need to read values from a JSON input in python which might be missing any key or value in the input. I Wrote this wrapper around the builtin dicts of Python to make handling errors easier when the JSON input is missing keys or values.

```
class DictAccessor:

    def __init__(self, to_access: Optional[Dict[Any, Any]]):
        self._payload = to_access

    def access(self, key: Any) -> "DictAccessor":
        if isinstance(self._payload, dict):
            return DictAccessor(self._payload.get(key))
        return DictAccessor(None)

    def get_value(self) -> Any:
        return self._payload

    def handle_error(self, err_callable: Callable[[None], None]) -> "DictAccessor":
        if self._payload is None:
            err_callable()
        return self

    def type_check(self, the_type) -> "DictAccessor":
        if not isinstance(self._payload, the_type):
            return DictAccessor(None)
        return self


d = json.loads('{"a":{"c":42},"x":"x"}')

should_be_the_answer = DictAccessor(d)\
    .access("a")\
    .access("c")\
    .type_check(int)\
    .handle_error(lambda : print("err"))\
    .get_value()
```

I know this is some design pattern I saw somewhere else (something related to functional programming i think). However, I can't recall the name. This code not just chaining (of function calls). There is also kinda the idea of a maybe in there but it also doesn't fully describe the pattern.

There also might be a variantion where get_value looks like this

```
    def get_value(self, value_callback: Callable[[Any], None]) -> "DictAccessor":
        value_callback(self._payload)
        return self
```

How does one call this pattern of handling errors in a chain of operation or accesses where each one might fail?

Comment: I would call it [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). Why do you say it's "not just chaining"?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini You are correct. I do use method chaining here. Heowever, I do more than just method chaining. I want to know the name for the whole thing. Not just the method chaining part.